# Get power distribution from radiation pattern

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

I'm trying to get the power (or E-field, or antenna element) distribution of an antenna given the radiation pattern.

I know that if you have a power distribution \$P(x)\$ along the antenna to start with, you can find the radiation pattern:

$$
p(\sin \theta ) = \mathcal{F}_{kx}\left[P\left(kx\right)\right]
$$
where \$\theta\$ is the angle, \$k\$ is the wavenumber and \$\mathcal{F}\$ is the Fourier transform.

So I imagine that we can simply reverse this process to get the power distribution right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say power distribution do you mean the radiation pattern? Typically, folks in antennas talk about $G(\theta,\phi)$ for the 3D pattern, which is inherently a ratio of powers. When you're computing power, you end up taking a square-magnitude [i.e. dot product with itself], so you're losing some sort of information.

The radiation pattern has nothing to do with the power distribution along antenna, which is itself not really a sensical term; power isn't distributed along the antenna. Sure I guess you could multiply the voltage and current at points along the element, but that's not really useful information. In fact, what matters isn't the power but the ratios of voltage(s)-to-current(s), i.e. impedance(s).

The far-field can be computed from the Fourier transform of the current distribution (see [this link](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/applications/radiation.php)). Note that this relates **field components**, i.e. $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$, not power. So if you're given the radiated fields $\vec{E}_{\text{rad}}$ and $\vec{H}_{\text{rad}}$, you can take an inverse Fourier transform to derive the radiation current distribution $\vec{J}_{\text{rad}}$. However, this can be extremely tedious since you often have to invoke contour integration to avoid singularities or do it numerically via some MoM-like code.

If you want to compute the power/gain pattern, what you typically do is find $\vec{E}_{\text{rad}}(\vec{r},\theta,\phi)$ and $\vec{H}_{\text{rad}}(\vec{r},\theta,\phi)$, evaluate the radiated Poynting flux $\vec{S}_{\text{rad}}(\vec{r},\theta,\phi)$, and then integrate over the solid angle $r^2d\Omega =r^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$. This gives you power, from which you can easily pull out gain.

I would recommend looking at the info at [Antenna-Theory.com](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/main.php). The site's author is completed his PhD studies at Arizona State under Prof. Balanis (the author of one of the more popular antenna textbooks).